# django is very slow on my machine

Tags: python, django, dns

I have a fresh install of django 1.0 and a simple page served from it takes 5 secs to load. On my colleague's computer it takes almost no time.

I start the server using

```
python manage.py testserver
```

I can see each GET request (PNGs and style sheets) take about half a second.

Another weird thing, which I think is related, is that the functional tests for the app run much slower on my machine with MySQL (on order of 100 times slower than on my colleague's machine). When I set the app to use sqlite, they run pretty quickly. I would like to exclaim that sqlite doesn't much change the time it takes to load a page, but it does speed up server startup.

It looks like IO problem, but I don't see general performance problems on my machine, apart from django at least.

Django runs on python2.4, I'm running Vista. I have also checked python2.5.

Thanks ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, It must totaly be a DNS problem, because the page loads up quickly as soon as
instead of http://localhost:8000/app I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.

But what could it be caused by? My host file has only two entries:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
```

Comment: Is this the first time you request the page or every time?  Also, when you use runserver is it the same?

Comment: This is the most stupid bug but I've run into in my whole life! My hosts file is empty because in Windows 7 those two lines are processed [in the dns server itself](http://serverfault.com/questions/4689/windows-7-localhost-name-resolution-is-handled-within-dns-itself-why). And same symptoms! Adding "127.0.0.1 localhost" line resolves it. Thanks, man!

Comment: you can do 'Invalidate Cashes | Restart' your PyCharm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firefox has a problem browsing to localhost on some Windows machines. You can solve it by switching off ipv6, which isn't really recommended. Using 127.0.0.1 directly is another way round the problem.

Comment: Same problem and solution under Chrome under Windows 7.

Comment: Same problem and solution in Chrome in OS X. I've heard rumors that this happens because the OS chooses IPv6 or IPv4 to try first and it has to wait until the first request fails before it will try the other version.

Answer (score 10):

None of these posts helped me. In my specific case, [Justin Carmony](http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/) gave me the answer.

**Problem**

I was mapping [hostname].local to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts file for easy development purposes and dns requests were taking 5 seconds at to resolve. Sometimes they would resolve quickly, other times they wouldn't.

**Solution**

Apple is using .local to do some bonjour magic on newer Snow Leopard builds (I think i started noticing it after updating to 10.6.8) and Mac OS X Lion. If you change your dev hostname to start with local instead of end with local you should be all set. Additionally, you can pretty much use any TLD besides local and it will work without conflict.

**Example**

test.local could become:

- local.test.com
- test.dev
- test.[anything but local]

and your hosts file entry would read:

```
local.test.com  127.0.0.1
```

*Note: This solution has the added benefit of being a subdomain of [hostname].com which makes it easier to specify an app domain name for Facebook APIs, etc.*

Might also want to run `dscacheutil -flushcache` in the terminal for good measure after you update /etc/hosts

Comment: this also solved it for me and i'm a windows user :-) thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem in the past. It can be solved by removing the following line from your hosts file.

```
::1         localhost
```

Once that's gone you should be able to use localhost again, quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Since you report your friend's machine has no delays, and I assume yours and his are comparable computers, it could be a DNS related issue. Try to add both the client's and the server's IP address to the server's hosts file.

If you run Django on *nix, it's the `/etc/hosts` file. If run it on MS Windows, it's the `%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS` file. (They are text files and can be edited by your favourite text editor.)

Comment: 5 second delay always sounds like name resolving issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the development server, it's not optimized for speed nor security. I noticed that specially serving static files (i.e. media) is slow.

Answer (score 2):

And if all else fails, you can always [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) your application and see where exactly is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem too, I've noticed it with Firefox on Vista and Windows 7 machines. Accessing the development server 127.0.0.1:8000 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to Django 1.3 or newer.

If you still have this problem in 2012 (using Chrome), make sure you're upgrading. In 1.3, a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16099) was fixed related to slowness when the dev server was single threaded.

Upgrading solved my issues. I was running Django 1.2 since that's the default on Debian Squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but it was caused by mysqld.

The app worked pretty fast on production with wsgi and a mysql server in the same host but slow in the development environtment with the django runserver option and a remote mysql server.

I noticed using "show processlist" that connections in database where stuck in the state "login" with user "unauthenticated user" and this make me notice that the problem where in the authentication process.

Looking for the real problem, I finally noticed that mysqld was trying to get the dns name of my ip and disabling the name dns resolution, I fixed the problem.

To do that, you can add this line into my.cnf file:

> skip-name-resolve

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue like this:

go to `setting.py` and set

```
DEBUG = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable AV Scanning & see if that makes a difference. It could also be caused by Vista. Upgrade to the latest service pack and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To completely bypass localhost without altering the hosts file or any settings in Firefox you can install the addon [Redirector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5064) and make a rule to redirect from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Use these settings

```
Include pattern : http://localhost*
Redirect to     : http://127.0.0.1$1
```

Leave the other fields empty.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem.

the solution was :

- I was trying to start localy a version that was usualy deployed on a webserver in production.
- The static files in production were served by an apache config and not with django static serve

so I **just uncommented back my static serve urls** :/

Answer (score 0):

**Slow Loading of Static Files**

If you notice that static and media files (images, style sheets, etc.) are particularly slow to load, the problem might be Django's development server (`python manage.py runserver`). As noted by [hassen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/362895/5916915), that server is not optimized for speed.

You can try using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) `runserver_plus` command with the `--threaded` option as a replacement for Django's `runserver` command. Under the hood, it uses Werkzeug as the threaded WSGI server. You may notice a huge improvement in loading times for static files.

Also see: [Making Django development server faster at serving static media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358450/)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was Django Debug Toolbar - its amazingly helpful when its needed but when it isn't it can slow development down which can be extremely frustrating and hard to identify. I find its better to disable it during development unless you need it. :zombies-never-die:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).