# Making Django development server faster at serving static media

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Django `manage.py runserver` for developing my application (obviously), but it takes **10 seconds** to completely load a page because the development server is very, very slow at serving static media.

Is there any way to speed it up or some kind of workaround? I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: How can your page be that large?  What size files are you presenting?  Where is your static media kept?  You're running on one computer through `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, right?  If so, it should run amazingly fast.  Are you serving static content through Django view functions?  If so, that's a mistake.

Comment: The total weight of a page is around 53 kilobytes, no more - but that includes many stylesheets, images and JavaScript files. I'm using the static media view included with Django for development.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using [`mod_wsgi`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) instead, and having httpd handle the static media.

Comment: +1: Don't speed it up.  Consider fixing your development environment to use a proper server.  Or, consider finding out why your static media is so slow.

Comment: How do I set up mod_wsgi in a way that it will function like the development server, reloading any changes automatically?

A quick Google search returned something that seemed to be a solution that didn't work in Windows.

Comment: There is an entry in the wiki there specifically on reloading, with a section that discusses Win32 issues.

Comment: What's interesting, is that the reloading code from mod_wsgi works for any Django management command, which means you can have auto-restart of management script on e.g. svn update.

Answer (score 5):

Development server is simple unsafe single-threaded application, so you cannot do much.

One trick you could try is to redirect /site_media to second development server, but this is ugly and probably wouldn't help that much. So you could try bundling/compressing multiple assets into one css/js (e.g. using [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)).

And in any case, you should have separate static media server, that can serve multiple assets at once.

Answer (score 4):

Install Firefox (if you haven't already), and install the [Firebug Add-On](http://getfirebug.com/). Restart your browser. In the lower-right corner click the "bug" icon and make sure that in the "Network" tab (it's a dropdown) of the Firebug panel that opens at the bottom of the browser, the network monitor is active.

Now with the network tab of Firebug open, open your Django-generated page that you observed to load slowly. Take a look at the timeline bars. You'll notice that the colored fragment(s) of each bar indicate(s) the reason for each request's total "load" time. Violet, for instance, means that actually the browser is waiting for the server to generate the response. Gray means it's receiving content. And so on. Hovering over the bars will display a color legend.

With Firebug's network monitor you should be able to pinpoint how exactly your browser and/or server are spending their 10 seconds.

Comment: The actual download of an asset doesn't take any time, but the development server can apparently only handle one request at a time, causing the slowness (?).

Comment: "one request at a time" - it's because it's single threaded so all requests are serialized in queue.

Answer (score 2):

Run lighttpd to serve the static content and use the MEDIA_URL to point the pages at the lighttpd server that servers the static stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) `runserver_plus` command with the `--threaded` option as a replacement for Django's `runserver` command. Under the hood, it uses Werkzeug as the threaded WSGI server. You may notice a huge improvement in loading times for static files.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning fast ans easy on resources when using NGINX for serving static and media files. Here's how it goes. However, you'll need to adapt some paths according to your use case and system. But I think this will get you started:

1) Download NGINX for your system, in your case Windows:
http://nginx.org/

2) Unpack the zip file. Here's how your NGINX config file may look like. This file lives inside `nginx/conf/`:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    # root path to your project
    # use "..." if spaces are in the path
    # you may add a drive letter if required, e.g. root c:/foo
    # use / instead of \. It's simpler and works
    root /example/path/django/project/;
    server {
        # any free port number will do; Django dev server usually runs on port 80
        listen 8000 default;
        server_name localhost; # or 127.0.0.1
    }
}
```

3) Start NGINX by calling the `nginx.exe` - no options needed.

4) Tweak your Djnago project's `settings.py` file:

```
if DEBUG:
    STATIC_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/'
    # against Django recommendation, I often still use the static
    # directory for user uploads; old-style Django ;-)
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/static/uploads/'
```

Now, the static URLs in Django should look something like this:
http://localhost:8000/static/js/base.js

... 5) Stop the server by calling:

```
taskkill /f /IM nginx.exe
```

Well, that's it. I typed this quickly, so just let me know if anything's unclear or not working for you. I may improve this answer accordingly.