# django's dev server very slow at times on OSX

Tags: django, macos

When I run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The development server starts up with no error messages but sometimes when loading a page will just hang for a min or two then very slowly load the page.  Im running OSX 10.6.6, virtualenv, django 1.3, python 2.6.1, mysql.  Happening on more than one project on 3 different macs.

Anyone else having the same issue?

Occasionally I'm seeing this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/webdev/99/svn/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Users/x/webdev/99/svn/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Users/x/webdev/99/svn/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Users/x/webdev/99/svn/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/Users/x/webdev/99/svn/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 284, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: buy a better machine / write better code. If you think that's not the problem, try debugging your code to see how much time each function is consuming (print a string on the beginning and end of a function) to see what's causing the delay

Comment: It runs fine in Ubuntu on a slower machine so I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: Is it still slow if you use sqlite?  For a while I had to develop with sqlite because using mysql was so slow on my mac.

Comment: The Broken pipe just oocurs when the sourcecode is reloaded and is completely normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was static media slowing me down so I now serve them via apache. Problem solved.

[Making Django development server faster at serving static media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358450/making-django-development-server-faster-at-serving-static-media)

Answer (score 1):

Had no problems with Django on OSX and made several projects with it.

As [tiagoboldt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637499/tiagoboldt) suggested you might want to check the code for bottle necks. The debug toolbar helps to analyze query performance.

Also there's some good advice at http://jacobian.org/writing/django-performance-tips/