# Django server don't respond

Tags: django

After execute `./manage.py runserver` which works rather fine, sometimes server doesn't respond, such as it would be turned off.

I tried google-chrome, opera or just ping it under Arch Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django is very slow on my machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362808/django-is-very-slow-on-my-machine)

Comment: I have already used ip address to access my site. And for it doesn't respond at all, even after some time.

Answer (score 1):

My Django dev server was responding slowly, and I couldn't figure it out. But once I started using Mac OS X's built-in Apache instead of `django.views.static.serve` to server my static files, everything started responding quickly again.

Since you're using Linux, maybe you can set up Apache to serve your static files and see if that works?

I think my slowness was due to having either too many files or a file that was too large being served by `django.views.static.serve` that caused the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but problem concern all site, not only static files. Moreover after reboot usually it repairs, and it's ok for some time. And after another reboot, or even without it, server stop working.

Comment: That was happening with my project too: the whole thing would slow down or simply not respond. I now develop with static files served by apache and haven't run into slow downs since.